# Capture a single image with IP camera using python

Tags: python

I just want to capture a single image from IP camera using python.
I had this below sample code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while(True):

    ret, frame = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

But I don't need to show preview, also no need of capturing frame by frame..It should be like when program starts it just take a picture and save it in some folder and stop execution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If saving the first frame is the only thing you need...

```py
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
if cap.isOpened():
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret:
        cv2.imwrite('frame.png', frame)

cap.release()
```

Comment: @ChakriChinnu you're welcome. Please mark the answer as accepted if that solved your issue :)